# Django can't find static files

Tags: python, django, nginx, static, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my Django project on [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com). I've chosen Django App droplet to make it more simple.

Then I've simply installed requirements, replace their `django_project` to my project.

The problem is that static files (at least `css`) doesn't work at all. I can see the web but no `css`.

Settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/django/SolutionsForLanguages_2/SolutionsForLanguagesApp/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I've followed this tutorial [One-Click Django - DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-django-one-click-install-image)

Did `python manage.py collectstatic`
I've already tried to restart `gunicorn`.

nginx/sites-available/django:

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/SolutionsForLanguages_2/SolutionsForLanguagesApp/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/SolutionsForLanguages_2/SolutionsForLanguagesApp/static; 
    }

    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

`CSS` works for `Django-Admin` pages

**IMPORTANT EDIT**;

I've checked nginx log and it seems that it tries to find these files in wrong path. It is searching in their default project path.

```
2016/08/09 06:31:29 [error] 998#0: *140 open() "/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1", host: "37.139.20.125", referrer: "http://37.139.20.125/"
2016/08/09 06:31:29 [error] 998#0: *142 open() "/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/css/jumbotron.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /static/css/jumbotron.css HTTP/1.1", host: "37.139.20.125", referrer: "http://37.139.20.125/"
2016/08/09 06:31:29 [error] 998#0: *140 open() "/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/css/dropdown.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /static/css/dropdown.css HTTP/1.1", host: "37.139.20.125", referrer: "http://37.139.20.125/"
2016/08/09 06:31:29 [error] 998#0: *143 open() "/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /static/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css HTTP/1.1", host: "37.139.20.125", referrer: "http://37.139.20.125/"
2016/08/09 06:31:30 [error] 998#0: *140 open() "/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/img/hourglass.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /static/img/hourglass.png HTTP/1.1", host: "37.139.20.125", referrer: "http://37.139.20.125/"
2016/08/09 06:31:30 [error] 998#0: *142 open() "/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/img/value.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /static/img/value.png HTTP/1.1", host: "37.139.20.125", referrer: "http://37.139.20.125/"
2016/08/09 06:31:30 [error] 998#0: *143 open() "/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/img/people.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /static/img/people.png HTTP/1.1", host: "37.139.20.125", referrer: "http://37.139.20.125/"
2016/08/09 06:31:30 [error] 998#0: *144 open() "/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/img/howitworks.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /static/img/howitworks.png HTTP/1.1", host: "37.139.20.125", referrer: "http://37.139.20.125/"
2016/08/09 06:31:30 [error] 998#0: *140 open() "/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/img/languages.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /static/img/languages.png HTTP/1.1", host: "37.139.20.125", referrer: "http://37.139.20.125/"
2016/08/09 06:31:30 [error] 998#0: *142 open() "/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/img/logos.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /static/img/logos.png HTTP/1.1", host: "37.139.20.125", referrer: "http://37.139.20.125/"
2016/08/09 06:31:30 [error] 998#0: *143 open() "/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/img/pricing.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /static/img/pricing.png HTTP/1.1", host: "37.139.20.125", referrer: "http://37.139.20.125/"
2016/08/09 06:31:30 [error] 998#0: *144 open() "/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/img/fcb.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /static/img/fcb.png HTTP/1.1", host: "37.139.20.125", referrer: "http://37.139.20.125/"
2016/08/09 06:31:30 [error] 998#0: *140 open() "/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/img/twitter.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /static/img/twitter.png HTTP/1.1", host: "37.139.20.125", referrer: "http://37.139.20.125/"
2016/08/09 06:31:30 [error] 998#0: *142 open() "/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/img/linkedin.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /static/img/linkedin.png HTTP/1.1", host: "37.139.20.125", referrer: "http://37.139.20.125/"
2016/08/09 06:31:30 [error] 998#0: *145 open() "/home/django/django_project/django_project/static/img/helpful.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 89.103.231.4, server: _, request: "GET /static/img/helpful.png HTTP/1.1", host: "37.139.20.125", referrer: "http://37.139.20.125/"
```

Comment: If you navigate to a single CSS file in your browser does nginx display it or list 404?

Comment: @MattWritesCode Yes, it displays not found. 404 error

Comment: Have you checked file permissions on
/home/django/SolutionsForLanguages_2/SolutionsForLanguagesApp/static

Is it readable.

Comment: If you mean whether I can see those files for example using Putty, I can.

Comment: I've tried already to change permissions using answer here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/django-can-t-load-static-files-from-template-using-ubuntu-14-04-django-droplet

Comment: I've checked nginx log and it seems that it is looking in a wrong path. There were default project I've rewritten and it looks like it is searching in this old project (the path is wrong). I've updated the question with this log.

Comment: Reloaded the nginx configuration?

Comment: @MattWritesCode Thanks! Now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your log file is showing nginx looking for files to server but from the wrong location then it because you nginx file has not be updated since your last change.

[Reload your nginx configuration](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#control) and it should start serving files correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying STATIC_ROOT as following:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
# Note that number of times os.path.dirname is used depends on 
# to reach top of your project directory. here
# Static Files
STATIC_ROOT = join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static'), ]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```